# ¿Cuál es la alternativa a OPTION (FORCE ORDER) de SQL Server para PostgreSql?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Estuve en búsqueda de una opción similar a `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` de SQL Server, para [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) y no encontré nada. ¿Existe? Lo he usado en SQL Server en Consultas grandes y pasan de demorar 5min a 0.5seg.

Dejo una reseña para los que no saben para que sirve `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` en Sql Server:

> Cuando se pone esta sentencia a la consulta, se indica a SQL Server que cuando se ejecuta la sentencia no cambie el orden de las uniones (JOIN) en la consulta. Se unirá a las tablas en el orden exacto que se especifica en la consulta. Normalmente, el optimizador de SQL Server reorganiza el orden en que se piensa que va a ser óptimo para su búsqueda.
>
> Para utilizar la sugerencia de consulta FORCE ORDER, tendrá que añadir esto al final de la consulta.

Comment: En la documentación oficial explican como atender esto. El concepto es [explicit joins](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/explicit-joins.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí, puedes hacer lo mismo en PostgreSQL con la configuración `join_collapse_limit = 1`.

Puedes leer sobre los [explicit joins (inglés)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-joins.html), o especificamente sobre [join_collapse_limit](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-JOIN-COLLAPSE-LIMIT).

Por ejemplo:

```
SET join_collapse_limit = 1;
SELECT *
FROM foo
JOIN bar ON bar.foo_id = foo.id
RIGHT JOIN baz ON baz.bar_id = bar.id;
```